# Firebase auth token expired even though it is not

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

The stack is Angular 14, firebase 9.12.1, angular/fire 7.4.1.

I need help. I read over the docs for firebase auth, and how to handle auth with tenants. The implementation is good, I have my app sign-in with Google Provider and tenants. The project uses Google identity Platform.

The problem that I am facing is on the reload/refresh of the page. Before we started using identity, we were using firebase auth, the user would login once, and after that I would check auth state and if everything was ok, the user would not need to login again.

I had the below code on a service that is run on Angular APP_Initializer

```
import {
  authState,
  User
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

async checkUserAuth(): Promise<User> {
    const currentUser = await firstValueFrom(authState(this.auth));

    return currentUser || ({} as User);
  }
```

We just migrated to the Identity Platform and added tenants, the above no longer works. On the app bootstrap, the SDK makes an HTTP call using the appKey as a parameter and a payload with idToken as the user token.

https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=myprojectKey

Now, when the user  refreshes the page that call returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "TOKEN_EXPIRED",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "TOKEN_EXPIRED",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The thing is when I decode the token and check the value of `exp`, it is 1 hour from now, which is standard as per what I have read on firebase auth docs. The token lasts for 1 hour, and then uses the refresh token and life goes on. Nonetheless, I am getting the above error.

I checked if the tokens are changing between refreshes of the app, I compared the token used for the first login and then confirmed that it is the same when I refresh the page.

The docs suggest to use `onAuthStateChanged()`, so I changed the above code to this:

```
const auth = getAuth();
    auth.tenantId = 'my-tenant-id'; // *I hard-coded this to check if was the issue, it is not
    onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), async (user) => {
      if (user?.uid) {
        const currentUser = user as User;
        const firebaseToken = await (await user.getIdTokenResult()).token;
        //do stuff
      }
    });
```

The above also does not work, the identity HTTPCall returns the very error. The docs and answers I found on the internet are about people trying to expire tokens or persist sessions. Still, this app is targeted at modern browsers, specifically Chrome and Edge, current versions, so I don't need to change anything about that.

Does anyone know what I should be looking for? Or have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Estevão, I'm seeing the same problem... any ideas/suggestions, please?  Obrigado

Comment: @JosephSimpson honestly I don't remember what was it. But one of the things that impacted us is the use of tenants. Some things just don't work for tenants, such as using the SDK to verifySessionToken. If you use tenants, you need to do it manually. We learned that Token Expired gets throw sometimes for other things that are wrong. Sorry that I don't really remember what I have done to make it work, I will add a comment with some of things I remember that could cause problems

Comment: if you are using microsoft, make sure to add microsoft tenant id when calling your signin  from the sdk.
Make sure that the AuthDomain is correct. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices and make sure the authDomain matches the project with your auth. (likely not the problem, this would give other errors).

Those are the changes I see on git for that period. Sorry that I really didn't wrote down what I was doing wrong back then.

Comment: Thank you Estevão, I appreciate your effort!